# Passing Variables to a Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I get an error when I code the final line of the Test1 sub. It says "expecting =". Any ideas?

```
Sub selectByUsedRows(usedCol As String, selectCol As String)
n = Range(usedCol).End(xlDown).Row
Range(selectCol & "1:" & selectCol & n).Select
End Sub

Sub Test1()
Dim a As String, b As String
a = "A"
b = "B"
selectByUsedRows (a, b)
End Sub
```

**CORRECTED CODE FROM COMMENTS, THANKS!**

```
Sub selectByUsedRows(usedCol As String, selectCol As String)
n = Range(usedCol & "1").End(xlDown).Row
Range(selectCol & "1:" & selectCol & n).Select
End Sub

Sub Test1()
Dim a As String, b As String
a = "A"
b = "B"
selectByUsedRows a, b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `selectByUsedRows` as if you were calling a function.  You don't need the parentheses when calling a subroutine:

```
selectByUsedRows a, b
```

Comment: That fixed the first problem! Now I'm throwing an error '1004' inside the selectByUsedRows sub. It states Method "Range" of object '_Global' failed.

Comment: I improperly defined the range. All fixed and working! Thanks.